# jQuery AJAX function bizarre behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a rather odd scenario here, hoping someone might have some insight.

I have this function:

```
function get_jsonp(data){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:data,
        jsonpCallback:'pr',
        url:'http://example.com/api/'
     });
//alert("test");
}

$("a").live('click',function(e){
    $("#dialog").show();
    $(".hideable").hide();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    info = get_info();
    get_jsonp(info,'pr');
});
```

Under jQuery 1.4.1 this works consistently well.

Under jQuery 1.7.1 the first time its called there is no problem then when i click items that call it i get no results BUT if i un-comment that alert it works fine

any thoughts ?

Comment: Please describe "click items that call it"

Comment: I don't get it, you might have already navigated away from the page with `window.location = $(this).attr('href');` when you wanted the ajax call to fire...

Comment: i'm just trying to set what it says in the url bar without going anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as the `ajax` post is submit to the server, the method exits if you are using synchronous requests. What is happening is that your code that comes after `get_jsonp()` executes *before* the ajax call is actually complete. By having the `alert()`, you add just enough time before the method exits for the call to complete.

Unfortunately, `jsonp` doesn't support synchronous requests.

Consider using the [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) method or, if you can execute your subsequent code inside the `get_jsonp` method, catching one of the events:

```
function get_jsonp(data){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data:data,
        jsonpCallback:'pr',
        url:'http://example.com/api/',
        success: function(){
            // Do something when successfully complete.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: o i get what your saying but... that doesn't explain why it worked fine in 1.4.1 and shouuldn't the jsonpcallback be where everything after is run from

Comment: @mcgrailm: It was probably just a coincidence. That or 1.4.1 supported synchronous calls.

Comment: removing the callback and using success method fixed the problem thanks for your help